# What is the returned type by devres functions?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

I'm debuging a driver. And there are these type of statements:

```
/* Get the interrupt GPIO pin number */
gpiod = devm_gpiod_get_optional(dev, GOODIX_GPIO_INT_NAME, GPIOD_IN);
```

I've read about [devres](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/devres.txt) but I still not understanding what returns exactly?

I know that `gpiod_direction_output` returns a `struct gpio_desc`. But it seems it isn't the case with `devm_gpiod_get_optional`, because I've tried to print `gpiod->label` per example and I'm getting `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct gpio_desc'` error.

So if `gpiod` isn't a `stuct gpio_desc` what is then?

These are the includes:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/dmi.h>
#include <linux/firmware.h>
#include <linux/gpio/consumer.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/input/mt.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/acpi.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <asm/unaligned.h>
```

Comment: It seems to me that you have a forward declaration of `struct gpio_desc`, but not the actual structure *definition*. Perhaps you're missing some include file?

Comment: What does the kernel header file where `devm_gpiod_get_optional` is defined say it is?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the header where `struct gpio_desc` is defined on `drivers/gpio/gpiolib.h`. How do I make the include?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer the header is `consumer.h` and it's said to be `*gpio_desc`

Comment: Header `drivers/gpio/gpiolib.h` is internal (read its description at the beginning), so it seems you just shouldn't use fields of `struct gpio_desc`. The only thing you can do with that structure is to pass it to other functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the good style is to hide implementation details from API. That's what is done in case of `struct gpio_desc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gpiod** is also the pointer to **stuct gpio_desc**.

You can verify the same from your driver source code. All kernel driver has start using gpiod_* APIs. You need to enable the GPIOLIB from Kconfig if you are writing a new driver.

You can access the GPIO number using **struct gpio_device  *gdev** structure which is member of **struct gpio_desc**.

```
struct gpio_desc {
  struct gpio_device *gdev;
};
```

You need to pass the GPIO number through ACPI,device tree or platform data.
GPIOs mappings are defined in the consumer device's node, in a property named
-gpios, where  is the function the driver will request
through gpiod_get()

```
irq-gpios = <&gpio 1 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; //
```

Pls go through Documentation section of kerel for more understanding:

Documentation/gpio/consumer.txt
Documentation/gpio/board.txt

Answer (score 1):

> So if `gpiod` isn't a `stuct gpio_desc` what is then?

It seems, that you are confusing a struct object with *pointer* to struct object. The type of `gpiod` object is the latter, `struct gpio_desc *`.

The API uses [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer), a common scheme of *struct encapsulation*.

A consumer can access or modify the struct using public functions, which operate on object indirectly, via pointer. The direct access is forbidden, as it would require to place *definition* of the struct within consumer translation unit.

The typical code layout may look like as follows (the code is only illustrative):

#### Header file:

```
struct gpio_desc;

struct gpio_desc *create(void);
void modify(struct gpio_desc *);
```

#### Source file:

```
// include header file

struct gpio_desc
{
    int secret_field_1;
    int secret_field_2;
};

struct gpio_desc *create(void)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(struct gpio_desc));   // definition required here
}

void modify(struct gpio_desc *p)
{
    p->secret_field_1 = 100;                   // definition required here too
    p->secret_field_2 = 200;
}
```

#### API consumer:

```
// include header file

struct gpio_desc *gpiod = create();
modify(gpiod);
```

The idea is that consumer doesn't need or/and it's not supposed to know the internals of the struct. All operations are covered by calling public API functions.

Comment: Ok, understood. But then what I do if I only want to know which gpio number has been returned? On the consumer api I only see getters and setters of values and directions but not pin numbers.

Comment: Oh, could mayabe be this? `int desc_to_gpio(const struct gpio_desc *desc);`

Comment: Effectively. That functions is what I was looking for. Thank you.